# Sound blocking privacy fence

Tags: fence

Have a sound studio in the backyard, and the Electric utility just cut down numerous trees that buffered the sound from an adjacent highway. Is there a relatively inexpensive way to block sound from the highway along a 200' chain link fenced property line?

Comment: I have seen sound barriers behind where bands play at restaurants when neighboring businesses do not want the noise.  I'm sorry, but I don't know the brand name.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I personally know of, but don't know its name or manufacturer, that works quite amazing is for cyclone fences only & used by Golf Courses. Their version looks & feels like Astroturf & are just slats or strips that you feed into the cyclone netting. Really impressive at a course I used to play, where you're only 40' from a 4-lane highway.

Otherwise, [**here's one of many companies**](https://acousticalsolutions.com/product/aqfa-10-ext-exterior-absorber-sound-blanket/) who handle fence situations. That one's mostly blankets, but many others are slats or strips...Google - cyclone or chain link fence sound barrier. The Home improvement stores also offer aluminum mini-blind type slats, if you want to hide the sound treatment.

Sound Barrier Companies, may not sell for DIY

http://www.slimwall.com.au/acoustic-properties

https://acousticalsolutions.com/block-your-backyard-noise-with-a-noise-reduction-fence/

http://www.acoustiblok.com/acoustical_fence.php

http://www.soundbarrierfence.com/Sound-Barrier-Insulation.html

Priced DIY Sources

http://www.supersoundproofingsales.com/products.asp?dept=28

http://www.fencefabricsonline.com/noise-reducing-fence-cover

http://www.soundproofingamerica.us/products/

Cyclone Inserts, will do privacy and very minimal sound reduction.

http://www.yourfencestore.com/slats/ultimate-fence-slat.asp

http://www.homedepot.com/b/Lumber-Composites-Fencing-Chain-Link-Fencing-Chain-Link-Fence-Slats/N-5yc1vZc81o

Comment: Wouldn't those mats rot?

Comment: Yep, but nothing's forever. They're like a scotch-brite pad.

Comment: The site lists them as indoor products.  So they wouldn't be a good solution for outdoor noise.

Comment: I did some looking around and couldn't find them for interior (?) or exterior. But, I edited my answer to include the most current solutions.